# How to get the value of the selected cells that you pass through arguments as numbers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When Doing This Add Total Function I Made When It Adds The Selected Cells It Says That The Result Was Not A Number, But The Cells Selected Only Have Numbers.

```
function ADDTOTAL(ref1, ref2) {
  var Number1 = ref1;
  var Number2 = ref2;
  var Number = Math.floor(Number1+Number2); 
  return Number;
}
```

It returns #NUM! and says the result wasn't a number, I'm new to this and have no idea what it is.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

I managed to replicate your issue.

You are either passing strings instead of cell references:

[image: example]

or the values of the cells you use as references are strings. For example `"3 "`
is a string because it has an extra space but also `3` is formatted as string:

[image: example2]

Either way you pass strings but the arguments need to be numbers since you are doing a mathematical operation.

To make sure that the value of a cell is a number, do `=ISNUMBER(A1)`. If that returns `TRUE` it means that the value of `A1` is a number. To convert a string number into an actual number select the cells and go to `Format => Number => Number` on the top menu.

Keep in mind that if you add two strings together like `"3"` and `"1"` you won't get `4` but `31`. I deliberately changed the format to plain text. In this case again `=isnumber(A1)` would be `FALSE`:

[image: example3]

### Solutions:

Assuming that the cells are actual numbers, you have the following options:

- You pass the cell references:

[image: solution 1]

- You pass number arguments:

[image]

- Last but not least, you can use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert the input arguments into numbers:

  ```
  function ADDTOTAL(ref1, ref2) {
  var Number1 = parseFloat(ref1);
  var Number2 = parseFloat(ref2);
  var Number = Math.floor(Number1+Number2); 
  return Number;
  }
  ```

Comment: You wrote `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat` in the code snippet. Is that a typo?

Comment: It still returns #NUM! when I try the solutions and after i formatted it as a number

Comment: @Blade share a copy of your sheet but first remove all the sensitive information..

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TSgAy0QjezAXNvh3ERrFasq2USpSukim2T672NqHuyc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Blade make the sheet available to anyone by creating a shareable link. Now I don't have permission to see it.